# testing for support for history API returns true in IE

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing history API for my web app and of course IE doesn't support it. That's fine, I have a work around for it but when I test to see if there's support for the API, I'm not getting the expected result.

This is the offending line:

```
if (window.history) {
```

The problem is that in IE, it shows as true. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. IE does support some history stuff, for instance `window.history.back()`. You need to test for a more specific method or property of the history API. Try this:

```
if (window.history.pushState) { //Whatever code you want
```

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that IE does support history, so it might be the methods you are trying to call within the history api.